# Three.js : dynamic reflection (runtime)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm able to add objects in my scene on runtime.

I wanted to know (for objects reflection) if there is an other alternative than a cubecamera and envMap ? 
I haven't seen such an exemple so far.

I'm currently using cubeCamera. But the problem is that if I'm adding a lot of objects with their own cubeCamera their will be some performance issues..

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

Comment: Yes I saw this example, but it is a meterial. My objects are MeshStandardMaterial and have texture.. :/